# OS X configurations partially lost when sharing home directory with Linux

Tags: linux, macos, arch-linux, hfs+

I've installed Arch Linux on my Macbook Pro with OS X 10.8.5. I created an HFS+ volume(journalling disabled) for home directories so that my personal data can be shared between the two OSes. Sometimes, after rebooting to OS X from Arch, some(but not all) of my OS X configurations, such as trackpad settings, language settings, "Open with" for a particular type of file and etc, will be lost. I'm new to OS X but I think these configurations are stored in ~/Library and shouldn't be touched by Linux. So what's happening? Have anyone experienced the same thing?

I've noticed once that the shared home volume is automatically mounted as read-only after rebooting Linux. There was a message in the kernel log(dmesg) says the volume was not umounted cleanly and fsck is required. Seems that the HFS+ volume is not handled properly by Linux. Is this the reason to my problem?

Here's my fstab for Arch. It is generated by the install script.

```
# /dev/sda6
UUID=17c8408b-2161-42da-b5d0-c810af0ed430       /               ext4            rw,relatime,data=ordered        0 1

# /dev/sda1 LABEL=EFI
UUID=70D6-1701          /boot/efi       vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro   0 0

# /dev/sda4 LABEL=Home
UUID=7d5b66ee-5bff-318e-a012-71513315df75       /home           hfsplus         rw,relatime,umask=22,uid=0,gid=0,nls=utf8     0 0

# /dev/sda5
UUID=dd2dbecf-d699-4469-95f2-4ad3681e93ba       none            swap            defaults        0 0
```

Comment: Sharing your home folder between different installs is never a good idea: many programs store configuration files in it, and they may conflict even if you are running the very same version of the same package, which you cannot possibly be doing. In your shoes, I'd put all my data in a folder /home/myname/common_data, and would mount that, not the home folder. The alternative is writing some software to distinguish different boots and configurations, a trivial and tiresome task.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae In fact, I do want to share configurations of some applications in both systems, because I'm a heavy user of open source software. I've shared my .bashrc, .vimrc, .emacs and event my firefox profile. All these applications works fine. The only things lost is some OS X related configurations. I believe these configurations are stored in ~/Library and shouldn't be tampered in Arch by default. That's why I feel confused.